# Reloading Bluimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am building an app to upload files into different folders. To change the folder I have a `select` menu, and to this I have a jQuery function that loads the different folders for upload.

The upload itself works fine, but the problem is that every time the `select` menu the items in that particular folder is appended to the list, and if I change the folder in the `select` menu the list just get bigger and bigger.

I would like to reload the fileuploader completely every time the `select` menu is changed/updated.

This is how my change function looks

```
$("#test55").change(function () {  

    //Get value from the select menu
  var value = $("#test55").val();


    //Read the configuration file for the uploader
  $.getScript("/js/bluimp/js/main.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

  });

  //Sets a sessions variable so the script knows where to save the file
  $.post("/js/bluimp/server/php/process.php", { q: value }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

}).change();
```

I've tried using the built-in `$('#fileupload').fileupload('destroy');` function inside the change-function, but that prevents it from ever loading.

**Summary:** I want to completely reload the entire plugin every time the `select` menu is changed. If the plugin can't be reloaded I need to **flush the list** of files on every change in the `select` menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured I could just empty the table manually every time the menu changes. This is the complete script:

```
$("#test55").change(function () {  

   //++New line // Removes old table rows.
  $(".template-download").remove();
    //Get value from the select menu
  var value = $("#test55").val();


    //Read the configuration file for the uploader
  $.getScript("/js/bluimp/js/main.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

  });

  //Sets a sessions variable so the script knows where to save the file
  $.post("/js/bluimp/server/php/process.php", { q: value }, function(data) {
    //$('#form').slideUp('slow');
    console.log(data);
  });

  $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: '/js/bluimp/server/php/'
    });
}).change();
```